# How to sort keys in json by another json values

Tags: arrays, json, algorithm, sorting, key

I have two jsons.

First: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shmHP.jpg)

Second: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M56V6.jpg)

How to sort second json by first? I want to sort keys and it's values in second json by values in first json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
var first = ["name0", "name1", "name2"]
var second = { {"name2":"xyz", "name0" : "xyz", "name1" : "xyz" } } 
for( var i = 1; i < Object.keys(second).length; i++ ){
  var aux = {}
  first.forEach(function(element2) {
     resul[element2] = second[i][element2]
  });
}
```